# Getting a list of members from google apps domain group

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I have a none google apps admin account (regular user) that I want to run a google app script that pulls the member list of a google group. The way I'm currently going about it is to use the AdminSDK but don't know how to authorize this regular user to pull the group members list.

Not surprisingly when I run:

```
    var listOfUsers = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupname);
  Logger.log(listOfUsers);
```

I receive the "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".

I'm figuring I need to use oauth2.0 but I can't find any google app script implementations to look at. Also I've created an API project in the developer console but am unsure if I have the correct settings/permission for this regular user to use the API.

Can anyone point me on how to implement oauth2.0 or preferably a code snippet of how its done in google app script? And what settings do I need to enable in the API project in google developer console for this user to have access to group information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to get the members of the group, and not do anything with modifying the group, you can use GroupsApp.

You can also use the hasMember method if you want to verify membership, say against Session.getActiveUser();

Here is a simple example :

```
function getGroupMembers() {
  try {

    var groupEmail = 'cyrus-apps-script@googlegroups.com';
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail);
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++){
      // do something witty with the list of users
      Logger.log(users[u].getEmail());
    }

  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly for me. I got the list of users without having to do any complicated authorization.

Comment: You can also utilize your Google Group for a basic ACL mechanism.  there is a .getRole method, and based on the role, invoke different logic / permissions in your script...  Happy Coding!

Comment: unfortunately, it looks like GroupsApp getUsers only list members with a valid Google account